# How can I add empty elements into a grid to make it full?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have an app that gets data of employees and displays their attendance inside the company building.
[image: The app]

Each employee is assigned a card and all employees are displayed inside a grid.
I would like to do 2 things:

- give a background to the whole grid, so that if there's not enough employees to fill the grid, it would be gray
- give each card a white line in between, by either a gap between the cards or a border

How do I do that?

1. If I apply a background color to the grid, the spacing of the cards doesn't apply (since there are no cards).
2. If I try to add another card by an after element, only a small, single "card-like" element appears, which is not enough to fill the whole space.
   [image: Problem 1]
   [image: Problem 2, with the small after element]

```
//CardGrid.tsx
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import { CardGridType } from "../types/componentTypes";
import { UserDataType } from "../types/general";

const CardGrid: React.FC<CardGridType> = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className="m-4 grid grid-cols-2 overflow-hidden rounded shadow-lg sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-6 xl:grid-cols-8 2xl:grid-cols-8">
      {data.map((d: UserDataType) => (
        <Card data={d} key={d.cas} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardGrid;
```

```
//Card.tsx
import React from "react";
import { UserDataType } from "../types/general";

const Card: React.FC<{ data: UserDataType }> = ({ data }) => {
  const { jmeno, prijmeni, pritomny } = data;

  const cardClass =
    "py-8 px-8 text-center text-xl text-white " +
    (pritomny ? "bg-emerald-600" : "bg-gray-400");
  return (
    <div className={cardClass}>
      <p className="card-text">
        {jmeno} {prijmeni}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Please share your advice if you have any idea on how to tackle the problem.